# Criteria - Ordenação por predicato com Join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, criteria

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma ordenação em Criteria para a seguinte `query`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Social social
         LEFT JOIN socialfavorite favorite ON (social.id = favorite.favoritedSocial_id AND favorite.user_id = 2)
ORDER BY favorite.id desc;
```

Transformei a parte da ordenação usando a API do Criteria:

```
Join<SocialUser, SocialFavorite> favorite = socialUser.join("socialFavorites");

                    favorite.on(builder.and(
                            builder.equal(socialUser.get("id"), favorite.get("favoritedSocial").get("id")),
                            builder.equal(favorite.get("user").get("alias"), search.getCurrentUserAlias())
                    ));

                    if (orderParam.getType().equals(OrderType.ASC)) {
                        return builder.asc(favorite.get("id"));
                    }
                    return builder.desc(favorite.get("id"));
```

Porém, sempre que o builder executa o `orderBy` acontece o seguinte erro:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'socialuser2_.alias' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: `socialuser2_.alias` está sendo informado onde na `query`?

Comment: É montado pelo Criteria, provavelmente quando faço Join, mas achei muito estranho ele se "perder" nisso

Comment: Sim, por isso que eu estranhei, eu dei uma olhada em documentação do Criteria noite passada, mesmo nos exemplos que encontrei na net, não encontrei nada parecido com o seu... Eu estou tentando encontrar uma solução aqui, se conseguir eu posto pra ti

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Estou tentando várias soluções há dias, tentei até com subquery porém deu o mesmo erro

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

Quando se esta na cláusula Join na API do Criteria, só é possível selecionar a chave primária da sua entidade, tornando as outras propriedades inacessíveis.